# How to inject components into another components in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Working on Vuejs project, let's suppose I have created 10 basic components, now i have to use these components into another container components. Now my question is how to inject these basic components globally on root level so that i don't need to inject into each separate container components ?

- what is the best approach to inject custom components globally in Vuejs
- how to use third party plugins globally for whole app ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation once?

Comment: Man i know first step is documentation for any framework, but that didn't clear my problems that's i asked here. @hamzox and why downvote ?

Comment: Because it's a very basic thing in Vue. There are lot's of blogs/stuff/article/tutorials available on internet regarding 'how to define a component globally in Vue' etc etc. You should have done some research before asking. 
(That's what Stackoverflow states)

Comment: Agreed, this is a very basic thing in Vue.  AND, you are asking two different questions at once... both of which are pretty clear in the excellent Vue documentation.  However, it would be easy to show a quick example of how to use Vue plugins, or mixins.

Answer (score 1):

Vue.component('component-tag-name', { // options});

if you are using a build process and seperate .vue files

```
import MyComp from './path-to-your-component'

Vue.component('component-tag-name', MyComp);
```

now you can use the component inside any other componentwithout locally registering it

```
<component-tag-nam></component-tag-name>
```

Answer to 2nd questions

lets take `axios` as an example

setup axios on the prototype of `Vue` object like this:

```
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
```

now you can use axios in  any component using `this.$axios`

example in created hook:

```
created(){
    this.$axios.get('url').then((res) => {
        //response
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for point 1- I did the same but got some errors while load see here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/q/47050776/5043867, For point 2- I did same using axios but using same this is not achieved outside the created method dont know why ?

Comment: @PardeepJain the component looks good but can you show how your registering the component in a main.js file

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a file which holds the imports for the components you want? Let's say they are grouped under `homepage` or something you would just have a `homepage.js` file which holds the imports:

```
import Component from '@/components/homeButton.vue';
// Etc.

export default {
    Component
    // Etc.
}
```

You would simply import this file whenever you would need this group of components. And use it in your component with a spread operator like this:

```
import homepage from 'somedir/homepage';

components: {
    ...homepage
},
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is a good alternate to avoid messy code. but thing again in this case too we need to import all component whether indirectly but we have to import. i want something which imports globally like we does in angular side. is there anything like same in VueJs ? second is can you please tell what is`@` while import as i am new to Vuejs.